# How to get numbers from an input to order from greatest to least

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I what to organize numbers from greates to least
This is what i have:

```
<label for="">Numbers</label><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="Number"><br><br>
    <button  type="button" name="button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>




function test() {
var numbers = document.getElementById("Number").value;
function myFunction() {
    numbers.sort(function(a, b){
      return a-b
    });
    console.log(numbers);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the input??

Comment: You don't have numbers you have one string, which may or may not be able to be converted to a number. You need an array to sort.

Comment: You never call `myFunction` and you don't have an array to sort either. Need a more detailed explanation of where you expect these numbers to come from and what you expect to do with them

Comment: the input is numbers, 2 or more

Comment: You'd like "the input is numbers, 2 or more", however, it isn't at the moment.

Comment: I what to sort the number that will put in the input, 2 or more numbers, from greates to list to the console

Comment: We're asking for an example input... will it have commas or spaces, or??... e.g. `1,2,3,4`?

Comment: @Bryan Please be aware this isn't a rent-a-coder site. As such you need to take on board what is being offered to you and learn from what is being provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `document.getElementById("Number").value` is a string. If you want to sort the numbers in your string you should split that string (by space, for example) and then sort the array.

Once you have that sorted array - you can create that string again (using the `join` function).

Check this example:

```js
function test() {
  var numbers = document.getElementById("Number").value;
  sorted = numbers.split(" ").sort(function(a, b){
    return a-b
  });
  console.log(sorted.join(" "));
}
```

```html
<label for="">Numbers</label><br><br>
<input type="text" id="Number"><br><br>
<button  type="button" name="button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

> Note that the `Array.prototype.sort` function doesn't work inplace - it returns a new array with the values sorted inside.

Comment: I created edited now and have the string, what i do now?

Comment: Not sure about your question "what i do now", but you have the entire code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort an array, so you'll need to split the value into an array:

```
function test() {
  var numbers = document.getElementById("Number").value;
  var result = numbers.split(",").map(Number).sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```